# Could PHP be faster than Apache direct file access or RewriteRule of mod_rewrite in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, caching

I'm confused. I have a PHP 5.6 script that is producing a .js JavaScript file. It echoes arrays using PHP loops, and also includes some plain-text non-PHP sections, and also reads ten smaller javascript files and echoes them to the client. The total final file size is 560KB, The server automatically compresses the output and it arrives at the client as 163KB compressed. It takes between 700 and 1400 milliseconds to arrive at the client.

I guess that I shouldn't complain, but it seemed to me that it didn't make sense to keep reconstructing this file via PHP, so I prepared a copy of the final file and gzencoded it with level 9 to a size of 160KB and tried skipping PHP and loading the file either directly or via a RewriteRule in .htaccess. It's now always taking betwen 1200 and 1600 milliseconds to arrive, according to Chrome's Network pane.

Is it possible that PHP is so fast that it's bad to cache the file? Or is there something that might need adjustment? This is all via shared hosting, so I don't have full control.

Comment: Sounds pretty off at first, but then again you have to keep in mind that a shared hosting uses a virtual file system, which makes it absolutely impossible to predict access and read duration. It might well be that such files get loaded from all around the world.

Comment: Thank you. It's so strange because the PHP script is reading at least ten files from the same apparent file system.

Comment: PHP usually uses a byte code cache. So those files are not read but taken from memory.

Comment: I mean 10 JavaScript "data" files, besides the PHP code files. I thought byte code cache would be just for PHP code files. But maybe that's the answer anyway: since the PHP script is called so often, the server is even caching the data files that it accesses...

Comment: Thanks @arkascha. That makes it sound like I need to turn my caching approach upside down.

Comment: If there's no specific treatment on the data files and there are just included, it might be smart to reconsider the structure entirely to leverage the browser's cache. Aka, separate the static portions from the dynamic data.

Comment: Thanks @Capsule; I'm switching to that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I was missing the point that it's all static data as pointed out by @Capsule. So by using my new scheme and putting it in a file I automatically activate support for sending back [304 responses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304) later via the ETag (after I set the appropriate Cache-Control [header](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html) in .htaccess).

The PHP system may be highly optimized as pointed out by @arkascha, but that's only helpful for the first time the user accesses the file; when max-age expires and they ask for it again, my PHP script doesn't contain a whole scheme to try to send back 304, so it has to send the whole file out again.